# Which design pattern will be best for football match app

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I am creating web api for application which support football team in collecting statistic data from matches. I am on implementing phase now. And lets say I am thinking what (if it is needed) type of design patter will be best for something like this:

```
 public class Shot
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PlayerId { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public bool OnGoal { get; set; }
    public int GameId { get; set; }

}
```

and

```
public class Card
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PlayerId { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public bool IsRed{ get; set; }
    public int GameId { get; set; }
}
```

As You can see some properties are same. It should be implemented with interface, inheritance ( f.e. class Action) or maybe I should use one of Design patterns (which one)? What will be best for Entity Framework to avoid problems in later phases?

Comment: Why card does not have game id?

Comment: Just missed it. I edited question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, both your classes represent some kind of game event - shot and card. There could be some other game events, like a free kick, throw in, substitution, penalty, or corner kick. All of these events should have id, game id, player id, timestamp, and probably comment. So your problem is the duplication of data in several classes. It is easily solved with inheritance. No patterns required:

```
public abstract class GameEvent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int GameId { get; set; }
    public int PlayerId { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Time { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

And various specific events

```
public class Shot : GameEvent
{    
    public bool OnGoal { get; set; }
}

public class Card : GameEvent
{
    public bool IsRed { get; set; }
}
```

You should also think about saving timestamp of added time because you can get both 46 minutes time span (start of second half) and 45+1 minutes of first half.

Comment: Thank You Sergey. I tought about inheritance but was not sure. If I could ask one more question. 
I would like to use code-first approach for entity framework. Is it ok to use properties like `public int PlayerId` or I should use `public Player player `

Comment: @MateuszSzymański it's totally ok to use Player, PlayerId or both of these properties.

Comment: About Time - it will be app for Beach soccer so there is no something like additional time so i have not care about that. Anyway - thank You

Comment: OP you should think very carefully about whether you want to subclass vs using an interface

Comment: @BKSpurgeon it's not *vs* thing. You can use both, but interface on its own will not solve data duplication problem

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy if use only property `PlayerId` in entity then will work Code First?